# composer and laravel 7 not working with php 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-8.1

Today i updated php in xampp to 8.1.0 after that all Laravel projects stopped in localhost.

So, after update composer.json from to

```
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
```

I see the composer have problem like this after run composer update or any composer command:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:277
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
```

How Can I solve this problem all my projects stopped because the composer have error.

Comment: Why would it? Laravel 7 doesn't support PHP 8 and was written before it.

Comment: Where did you see that Laravel 7 is compatible with PHP 8.1?

Comment: @Jaquarh so, what is the solution ?
All laravel 7 projects must be updated to laravel 8?

Comment: @BrianThompson so, what is the solution ?
All laravel 7 projects must be updated to laravel 8?

Comment: Well yes, if you want to use PHP 8 you need to use a compatible Laravel version.

Comment: @BrianThompson Laravel 7 (and 6) is still supported. The spec `^7.3|^8.0` means it works with 8.1.

Comment: You need to update composer; the error messages clearly come from within `composer.phar`. Just do `composer selfupdate`

Comment: @miken32 I see that that's true from the 6.X and 7.X branch in GitHub. I just checked the branch of the docs which I guess didn't get updated (just says `>=7.2.5`). Although now I've got to dig in further because I've seen several issues recently (myself and on SO) when using 8.1. But the [changelog](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#v8670-2021-10-22) shows it's been supported since October.. It's possible they have not been on the correct minor version. Usually you just get the major included in questions.

Comment: @miken32 `composer selfupdate` works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with the newest xampp, all i did was go back to 7.4.26 and now the installations of 6-7 work fine.

Comment: This is just a workaround. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: this is the solution.  laravel 7 is not forwards compatible with php 8.1

Comment: Laravel 7 reached EOL in March 2021 so the only solutions are (a) downgrade to an earlier version of PHP or (b) upgrade the web app to a later version of Laravel.